# Cloud services to notify on a script not succeeding for a long time

Tags: devops, monitoring, reliability

I have a python script that resides on a VPS, reads (each hour) financial news from a public datafeed and emails me when certain keywords of interest appear. That can happen only a few times a week, but such events are very important and must not be missed. On any data fetching or parsing error, I should also be notified via email, and errors of course get recorded into the server's local log file.

But how do I know that my smtp credentials are not blocked by the mail provider, or my VPS is not shut down by my hoster? In that case, I would not be notified and would be unaware of important events (and the failure to fetch/deliver them itself) until I decided to log into VPS manually and take a look at the logs.

Even if I would use a backup notification channel, e.g., SMS or Telegram, it still would not protect against cloud provider service disruption, or my account being blocked due to temporary payment issues, as there would exist no instance of the script to deliver the message on any of the channels. That's why I suspect some 3rd party fault-tolerant service is needed. Especially if I'm a freelance coder having lots of similar scripts, running on a mixture of VPSes, serverless/Lambdas, possibly for different end clients.

**What is the best practice you dear developers are using to be notified when some script has not  succeeded for a long enough time? I would like something reliable and ready-to-use, maybe you can recommend some existing monitoring services.** At least I was not able to find the ones that solve my particular problem straight away.

To clarify, I don't want to spend time on some manual checking until it's absolutely necessary (in this case, I can tolerate up to 2 hours, and if it does not self-heal within that period, then I need to be notified), and I obviously don't want to get regular annoying reports that the service is doing fine and there simply were no interesting news detected. Plus, I of course want to keep the costs reasonable.

Comment: Anatoly, if you are worried about the rare instances when big cloud service providers like AWS do go down - you can have your workload on multiple clouds - AWS, GCP, Azure. If the application is very critical, you might have to do this. For the part where you fear that your VPS might be blocked by the hoster - you can have a periodic health check message sent to you - say every few mins/hours. If you don't get this, say for N times, you can assume things are not good.

Comment: Thanks, I was also thinking about mirroring to another cloud providers, but it's costly and there are maintenance problems (multiple places to update source codes, track, install hotfixes). I'm worried not only about providers going down - my account with them could simply be blocked due to an expired card, political events, and so on.

Comment: To check if your instance is alive, you can use services like uptime robot.
To check the result of your script, you can simply write the result in a file and serve it in a way that same services (uptime robot) could check; If the result is OK, you don't need any alert, but if the result are not as expected or there is no result at all, you will be notify.

Comment: RoohAllah sounds amazing, esp. their feature Cron job monitoring, I'm checking them.